Is there any disadvantage to moving a small and frequently read read-only table to in-memory OLTP?
Suppose that you have a table which is:

Read from so frequently that it is almost always in RAM.
Very small.
Almost never changed.

Is there any disadvantage moving such a table to in-memory OLTP? My thoughts are that if it's always in memory anyway, then you should consider using the architecture designed for living in memory.

Doesn't something about the data structure make in-memory OLTP tables smaller and therefore faster to read? Rows are smaller than the pages required to hold them.


Doesn't something about the data structure make in-memory OLTP tables smaller and therefore faster to read?

Rows are not necessarily smaller, but defined as C-style structs, and accessed by generated native code.  This is faster to read in the context of a natively compiled stored procedure, but not faster to read and copy into a TDS network buffer and send to a client, or use outside of the context of a natively complied proc.
